# How do I Configure two https connector port in jboss 7?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I need to configure 2 https ports (5480 and 8443) in jboss 7 ( I did this jboss 5 adding one more connector port). I tried creating two https connector ports in standalone-full.xml but it did not work.

Following is my current configuration for 8443 https port  and I need another  port 5480 as well.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">

<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">

<ssl key-alias="tomcat" password="FOO@Bar-1" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/keystore" cipher-suite="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5" protocol="TLS" verify-client="false"/>

        </ connector >

</subsystem>
```

---

```
<socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you changed some configuration, your standalone jboss container reads configuration from standalone.xml rather than from standalone-full.xml. The "full" version is like an example file.